# Delta Epsilon Format limit Definition for a multi-variable function?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

Show that $\lim\frac{x}{y}$ as $(x,y)\to(1,1)$ equals $1$ by the delta epsilon definition.

$\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2} < \delta$ 
$|\frac{x}{y}-1| < \epsilon$

How do I proceed?

Comment: Try familiarizing yourself with mathjax for question formatting:)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2} < \delta$ implies $|x-1|<\delta$ and $|y-1| < \delta$.

> Then,
>  $$-\frac{2\delta}{1+\delta}=\frac{1-\delta}{1+\delta}-1<\frac{x}{y}-1 < \frac{1+\delta}{1-\delta}-1 = \frac{2\delta}{1-\delta}.$$
>  Choose $\delta$ small enough.